# runTest.ts class in vscode-test setup gets never used even in example project, what is it's use?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I am new to Typescript, JavaScript and VScode Extensions

I have a vscode-test setup as outlined here:

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/testing-extension#custom-setup-with-vscodetest

Modeled after the `helloworld-test-sample` from here:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/helloworld-test-sample

I want to download a vscode instance in the `runTest.ts` class `main` method and then install my extension on it. But by debugging I have found that the `runTest.ts` class is *never* called. The `index.ts` class *is*, the `extension.test.ts` class *is*, the tests run, but the `runTest.ts` class never is, which hinders me greatly, because I want to do what is shown in the first link.

This is also the case in the original example project, so I assume it is meant that way. But what is the purpose of the `runTest.ts` class then?

My goal is to actually install my extension in a test and see if it gets installed correctly and activated, but this fails because `downloadAndUnzipVSCode` fails when `await` is used and `resolveCliPathFromVSCodeExecutablePath` can only be used with a `Promise<String>`. So I am trying it like in the version shown in the first link.

Can someone maybe explain why the `runTest.ts` main method seems to be never called, and maybe how to implement a test that does download a VSCode instance, installs a local .vsix extension and evaluates if it was started correctly?

Thanks :)

Comment: I too am confounded by this!  I was somehow able to get it to run once but can't reproduce it!

Comment: It depends on the way you run the tests which classes are called. Look below for how to do it if you want them to be called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of launching a debug session from the vscode debug viewlet, you have to start the test task from the Terminal > Run Task menu item.  In package.json these scripts are in the [yeoman generated test extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension) and the last one runs runTest.js.

```
    "scripts": {
        "vscode:prepublish": "npm run compile",
        "compile": "tsc -p ./",
        "watch": "tsc -watch -p ./",
        "pretest": "npm run compile",
        "test": "node ./out/test/runTest.js"
    },
```